# Highcharts : point.key is too long and make chart small

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsf-2.2

i'm using `highcharts` with `jsf` and i'm facing a problem that i don't know how to solve .

The problem is that `point.key` is too long that it hides the chart it self and i need to keep the same height, what i want to do is to make point.key smaller by using ( `substring(0.15)` for example ) but in the same time i want the full `point.key` to display in the tool-tip header.

here is an image of my problem

[image]:

and here is my code :

```
$('#container-2')
                        .highcharts(
                                {
                                    lang : {
                                        printChart : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib1']}',
                                        downloadPNG : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib2']}',
                                        downloadJPEG : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib3']}',
                                        downloadPDF : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib4']}',
                                        downloadSVG : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib5']}',
                                        contextButtonTitle : 'Context menu'
                                    },
                                    chart : {
                                        type : 'column'
                                    },
                                    colors : [ '#808080' ],
                                    title : {
                                        text : '#{msg['DB_graph_title3']}'
                                    },
                                    subtitle : {
                                        text : ''
                                    },
                                    xAxis : {
                                        type : 'category',
                                        labels : {
                                            rotation : -45,
                                            style : {
                                                fontSize : '13px',
                                                fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    yAxis : {
                                        max : 100,
                                        min : 0,
                                        title : {
                                            text : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} (%)'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    legend : {
                                        enabled : false
                                    },
                                    tooltip : {
                                        pointFormat : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} : <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
                                    },
                                    series : [ {
                                        name : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']}',
                                        data : [
                                                <ui:repeat value="#{homeSupBean.campagnes}" var="camp">[
                                                        '#{camp.name}',
                                                        #{homeSupBean.campagneProg[camp.id.toString()]}],
                                                </ui:repeat> ],

                                        dataLabels : {
                                            enabled : true,
                                            rotation : -90,
                                            color : '#FFFFFF',
                                            align : 'right',
                                            format : '{point.y:.1f}', 
                                            y : 10, 
                                            style : {
                                                fontSize : '15px',
                                                fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } ]
                                });
```

if any one can help or have a better idea please don't hesitate, thank you.

Comment: You can use `xAxis.labels.formatter`, and add there your logic, for example:  `return this.value.substring(0, 15);`. It won't change original category's name, so tooltip will use proper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you mister @Pawel Fus, i found a solution similar to what you proposed.

It is to add Categorie in xAxis{} and put my logic in it and it worked fine.

here is my code :

```
$('#container-2')
                        .highcharts(
                                {
                                    lang : {
                                        printChart : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib1']}',
                                        downloadPNG : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib2']}',
                                        downloadJPEG : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib3']}',
                                        downloadPDF : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib4']}',
                                        downloadSVG : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib5']}',
                                        contextButtonTitle : 'Context menu'
                                    },
                                    chart : {
                                        type : 'column'
                                    },
                                    colors : [ '#808080' ],
                                    title : {
                                        text : '#{msg['DB_graph_title3']}'
                                    },
                                    subtitle : {
                                        text : '',
                                    },
                                    xAxis : {
                                        //here is the solution
                                        categories: [
                                                      <ui:repeat value="#{homeSupBean.campagnes}" var="camp">
                                                        ['<h:outputText value="#{camp.name.substring(0,5)} ..." />'],
                                                     </ui:repeat>
                                                     ],
                                        //Solution ends here                                                         
                                        type : 'category',
                                        labels : {
                                            rotation : -45,
                                            style : {
                                                fontSize : '13px',
                                                fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    yAxis : {
                                        max : 100,
                                        min : 0,
                                        title : {
                                            text : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} (%)'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    legend : {
                                        enabled : false
                                    },
                                    tooltip : {
                                        pointFormat : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']} : <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
                                    },
                                    series : [ {
                                        name : '#{msg['DB_graph_lib']}',
                                        data : [
                                                <ui:repeat value="#{homeSupBean.campagnes}" var="camp">[
                                                        '#{camp.name}',
                                                        #{homeSupBean.campagneProg[camp.id.toString()]}],
                                                </ui:repeat> ],

                                        dataLabels : {
                                            enabled : true,
                                            rotation : -90,
                                            color : '#FFFFFF',
                                            align : 'right',
                                            format : '{point.y:.1f}', 
                                            y : 10, 
                                            style : {
                                                fontSize : '15px',
                                                fontFamily : 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } ]
                                });
```